# Moving point charge --> using Maxwell induction integral to find B-field

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem. A point charge is moving with a uniform speed v. The question requires that I show how the Maxwell induction integral can be used to find the magnetic field $B$ in terms of the instantaneous distance $r$ from the charge and the angle $\theta$ that the radius vector $r$ makes with the direction of motion.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Please review the policy on homework questions here: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

I suggest you try something and then show some work and then ask something specific -- where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using the the "Maxwell induction integral" (I'm not even sure what that is), but you can solve your problem with the Lorentz force for magnetic fields:
$$\vec{F} = m\vec{a} = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$$
(If the particle is moving at relativistic speeds, stick a $\gamma$ in fron of $m\vec{a}$) The acceleration is given by the expression for centripetal acceleration.
$$a = \frac{v^2}{r}$$
where $r$ is the radius of rotation.

From here, note that because the force is given by a cross product, only the component of the magnetic field perpendicular to the velocity generates a force. Use this and the fact that the magnitude of a cross product is given by
$$|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\sin\theta$$
to get the full magnetic field vector.